# "Can't find operating system"

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 15.04, vaio

I did an install of Ubuntu 15.04 (after 14.04.3 didn't work b/c of 2 errors on disk) on an old Sony Vaio that was running windows 7. I finally got 15.04 to complete the download with no errors, but when I rebooted to complete the installation, I got a "can't find operating system" on a single terminal-looking line after the VAIO Bios screen came up. Oh yeah - I installed from a USB drive that was created with Universal USB Installer from Pendrivelinux.com

I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: Were you able to boot from the USB? Maybe your system is 32 bit and you downloaded 64-bit ubuntu?

Comment: Did you install Grub boot loader when the installer asked you to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this mate: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair.
I had similar problems before, and it helped. Did you install it manually or you relied on the installer?